Am I doing something wrong trying to share a link that sends me to a completely different answer?
I wanted to keep a link to this answer (this long link works as expected):
Concatenate compile-time strings in a template at compile time?
Original URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783400/concatenate-compile-time-strings-in-a-template-at-compile-time#answer-72510788

so I used the handy "Share" button and copied this short link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510788/212378
Original Short URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510788/212378

Only when I follow that shared short link, I end up on a completely different post / different answer:
C++ template string concatenation
Original URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693819/c-template-string-concatenation/4693941#4693941

Am I doing something wrong or is there some kind of bug(s) in Stackoverflow linking scheme?
I don't see how my browser would do it wrong. Also I checked in another browser where I don't use Stackoverflow and it did the same strange redirect...
Note: I show the URLs in code as well because some are replaced with the question and maybe it will change over time?

No repro, both of the first two links end up at the same page, highlighting the same answer by Cooler (Firefox 133.0.3 (64-Bit) on Windows 11), both clicking and copy pasting the link text.

Interesting. It works for me too now.
